# C# - Task always in 'WaitingForActivation' status

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task

I have the following method:

```
CancellationTokenSource taskController = new CancellationTokenSource();

public Task scheduleAction(Action action, DateTime ExecutionTime)
{
    DateTime eastern = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(
                DateTime.UtcNow, "Eastern Standard Time");
    Task WaitTask = Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(eastern).TotalMilliseconds, taskController.Token);
    WaitTask.ContinueWith(_ => action);
    return WaitTask;
}
```

Whis is called using the following lines:

```
Action start = () => startMonitor();
Task startTask = scheduleAction(start, DateTime.Now.Date + new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0));
```

This way the monitor can start at 8:00 everyday. But, the `Status`of the `Task` is always `WaitingForActivation`. I tried using the `Start()` method and it returns an `Exception="Start may not be called on a promise-style task."`.

Any clue how to make this work?

Comment: Why so complicated if you can just make it `public async Task scheduleAction ( ...) {await Task.Delay(...); action();}` ?

Comment: Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RATyMQ

Comment: Your method should utilize the async keyword and your Task.Delay should utilize the await keyword.

Comment: As a side note, the names `scheduleAction` and `WaitTask` are violating the [capitalization conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) of the .NET Framework. Should be `ScheduleAction` and `waitTask`.

Comment: Have you ruled out the possibility that there is an error at calculating the duration of delay? I suggest to try something simple like `Task WaitTask = Task.Delay(1000)` or `Task WaitTask = Task.Delay(-1000)` (to test how your program handles the exceptional case), before switching to the calculated duration.

Comment: I think what you missed was this: _"For the more common case in which you don't need to separate task instantiation from execution, we recommend that you call an overload of the Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew method."_ - [Task.Start()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Start)